# How to get button click from UIView to ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have created on custom View which contain one label and button 
I have created outlet for both in UIView class

[image]

I have one UIViewController in which i have subview that custom view
now i want to change label name and want to do something on button click.

```
let commonView = UINib(nibName: "CommonView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CommonView
        firstView.addSubview(commonView)


        commonView.lblCommon.text = "We can change label in particular Screen"
```

I am able to change label text but how can i get button action event in UIViewcontroller?

Comment: removed Objective-C tag from question as code snippet u posted seems to be in Swift

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use protocol

In your customView declare a protocol

```
protocol CustomViewProtocol : NSObjectProtocol{
    func buttonTapped()
}
```

Now create a variable in custom view

```
weak var delegate : CustomViewProtocol? = nil
```

In your viewController confirm to protocol

```
extension ViewController : CustomViewProtocol {
    func buttonTapped() {
        //do whatever u waana do here
    }
}
```

set self as delegate in view controller

```
let commonView = UINib(nibName: "CommonView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CommonView
        firstView.addSubview(commonView)
commonView.delegate = self
```

finally in IBAction of button in custom view trigger delegate

```
self.delegate?.buttonTapped()
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. I agree with your answer. Is that possible using Outlet only ?

Comment: @sss : If your view is in separate xib then UIViewController I afraid its not. But I believe even if its possible thats a very bad design. IBActions should be handled by the owner of UIComponents (not necessarily as another option mentioned above) but then I believe u should code considering design in mind not just because u can code. I believe my approach is little neater that way

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4:**

If you want to catch the tap within your `UIViewController` do this in the `viewDidLoad()` after you instantiate your view from a `nib` (eg called `aView`):

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
aView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Below `viewDidLoad` declare the following function and do whatever you want within its body:

```
@objc func tapAction() {

    //Some action here

}
```

*(**A note**: In Swift 4 the `@objc` annotation is obligatory, because it denotes that you want the function to be visible to the Obj-C runtime, which in `UIKit` handles (among other things) user interactions through its messaging system.)*

Since this `UIView` instance belongs in the view hierarchy of this `UIViewController` it makes sense to handle the taps within this `UIViewController`. This gives you the ability to reuse this `UIView` within any other `UIViewController` and handle its tap logic from the respective `UIViewController`.

In case there is a particular reason you want the taps handled within the UIView, you can use the delegate pattern, a closure, or in a more advanced implementation a Reactive framework (ReactiveSwift or RxSwift/RxCocoa)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it with RxSwift/RxCocoa:

```
view.rx
.tapGesture()
.when(.recognized)
.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
 //react to taps
})
.disposed(by: stepBag)
```

more ways to manage Gestures, can be found at the RxSwift github page: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxGesture